# Сжать размерность тензора с 3 до 1

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, pytorch

Есть матрица картинок.
[Count, 3,  493, 733]
(Количество,RGB,H,W)

Картинки переведены при помощи команды Grayscale в оттенки серого. Но размерность не поменялась. Shape по прежнему выдаёт - [Count, 3,  493, 733]. Как мне получить [Count, 1,  493, 733]??? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [документации](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Grayscale):

> Grayscale version of the input.
>
> If num_output_channels == 1 : returned image is single channel
>
> If num_output_channels == 3 : returned image is 3 channel with r == g == b

Предположу, что в коде необходимо переопределить количество выходных каналов:

```
Grayscale(num_output_channels=1)
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! так и сделал. Вот сегодня спрашивал подобный вопрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1352256/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-pytorch-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0 . Указал именно единицу.